# Displaying annotations on MapView with selection of a collectionView cell

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mapkitannotation

I have a program that is supposed to displayed annotations on a map based off of what collectionView cell is selected. But currently, when trying to select a collectionView cell, nothing appears on the map.

Here is the code.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

struct PlacesOnMap {
var name: String
var latitude: Double
var longitude: Double

init(name: String, latitude: Double, longitude: Double) {
self.name = name
self.latitude = latitude
self.longitude = longitude
}
}

class CollectionViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var mapView1: MKMapView!
var placesVal = [PlacesOnMap(name: "place 1", latitude: 12.9716, longitude: 77.5946),
                 PlacesOnMap(name: "place 2", latitude: 12.2958, longitude: 76.6394),
PlacesOnMap(name: "place 3", latitude: 11.4102, longitude: 76.6950)
]
var buildings = [PlacesOnMap(name: "buildings 1", latitude: 12.9716, longitude: 77.5946),
PlacesOnMap(name: "buildings 2",  latitude: 12.2958, longitude: 76.6394)
]
var recreation = [PlacesOnMap(name: "recreation 1", latitude: 28.54693, longitude: -81.393071),
PlacesOnMap(name: "recreation 2", latitude: 28.538523, longitude: -81.385399),
PlacesOnMap(name: "recreation 3", latitude: 28.542817, longitude: -81.378117),
PlacesOnMap(name: "recreation 4", latitude: 28.538985, longitude: -81.404694)
]

let reuseIdentifier = "cell" // also enter this string as the cell identifier in the storyboard
var items = ["Places", "Buildings", "Recreations"]
var displayCategoryText: String = ""


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

     mapView1?.delegate = self
}

// MARK: - UICollectionViewDataSource protocol
// tell the collection view how many cells to make
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.items.count
}

// make a cell for each cell index path
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    // get a reference to our storyboard cell
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell

    // Use the outlet in our custom class to get a reference to the UILabel in the cell
    cell.myLabel.text = self.items[indexPath.item]
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan // make cell more visible in our example project
    return cell
}

// MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegate protocol
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // handle tap events
    displayCategoryText = String(indexPath.item)
    checkDisplayCategoryText()
}

func checkDisplayCategoryText() {
    if displayCategoryText == "0" {
        setPlacesAnnotations()
    }
    if displayCategoryText == "1" {
        setBuildingsAnnotations()
    }
    if displayCategoryText == "2" {
        setRecreationAnnotations()
    }
}

func setPlacesAnnotations() {
       let places = placesVal.map { placeOnMap -> MKPointAnnotation in
       let place = MKPointAnnotation()
       place.coordinate =  CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: placeOnMap.latitude, longitude: placeOnMap.longitude)
       place.title = placeOnMap.name
       return place
       }
       mapView1?.removeAnnotations(mapView1.annotations)
       mapView1?.addAnnotations(places)
   }

   func setBuildingsAnnotations() {
       let places = buildings.map { placeOnMap -> MKPointAnnotation in
       let place = MKPointAnnotation()
       place.coordinate =  CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: placeOnMap.latitude, longitude: placeOnMap.longitude)
       place.title = placeOnMap.name
       return place
       }
       mapView1?.removeAnnotations(mapView1.annotations)
       mapView1?.addAnnotations(places)
   }

   func setRecreationAnnotations() {
       let places = recreation.map { placeOnMap -> MKPointAnnotation in
       let place = MKPointAnnotation()
       place.coordinate =  CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: placeOnMap.latitude,  longitude: placeOnMap.longitude)
       place.title = placeOnMap.name
       return place
       }
       mapView1?.removeAnnotations(mapView1.annotations)
       mapView1?.addAnnotations(places)
   }


   func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
        guard let annotationTitle = view.annotation?.title else
              {
                  print("Unable to retrieve details")
               return
              }
     print("User tapped on annotation with title: \(annotationTitle!)")
   }

}
extension CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let cellsAcross: CGFloat = 3
    var widthRemainingForCellContent = collectionView.bounds.width
    if let flowLayout = collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
        let borderSize: CGFloat = flowLayout.sectionInset.left + flowLayout.sectionInset.right
        widthRemainingForCellContent -= borderSize + ((cellsAcross - 1) * flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing)
    }
    let cellWidth = widthRemainingForCellContent / cellsAcross
    return CGSize(width: cellWidth, height: cellWidth)
}

}

class MyCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!

}
```

Here is a photo of the storyboard.

[Picture of storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KbAS.jpg)

How would I fix this so that depending on what collection view cell is selected, it displays the proper annotations on the mapView?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you have correctly set the `UICollectionView` delegate and dataSource in the Storyboard.

When you select a cell you set:

```
displayCategoryText = String(indexPath.item)
```

but then you don't do anything with that variable. You need to call a method that can use the value of that variable to pull the correct info out of your data model and then add the annotation to the map.

Comment: Is the variable not being called in the viewDidLoad function through the line, 'if displayCategoryText == "0" {
        setPlacesAnnotations()
    }'?

Comment: In ViewDidLoad you check the value of the variable and call setPlacesAnnotations is it equals “0” but then the the application flow leaves ViewDidLoad and doesn’t ever go back. All you do in `didSelectItemAt` is change the variable’s value. That has no bearing on the check that occurs in ViewDidLoad since app flow doesn’t go back through there. That’s why you need to initiate a check/method after the change.

Comment: How would I initiate a check/method after the change?

Comment: You need to write a function and call it after you set a new value to displayCatehoryText. You need to understand what all the possible values are for this variable and, in your function, check the actual value and Do the appropriate thing.

Comment: I've updated my code to include a function that checks the possible cases of displayCategoryText, but still get no annotations on the map.

Comment: It's difficult to help without sight of your entire app and the linkages with the storyboard. I appreciate that you're probably just trying out ideas here and it probably isn't your final app so having your data model inside your CollectionViewController (while not a good idea) is probably temporary but including the view methods and the controller code AND the model all together makes it difficult to untangle the knot. Do you have the project saved to Github?

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this for a solid 3 days and read pretty much every google article until I found the ONE that helped.

First get your annotations index inside the mapview(didSelect: )

let index = (self.mapView.annotations as NSArray).index(of: anno) *Anno is my view.annotation constant for my custom annotation view

Then if you want the collectionview to scroll to the correct cell by tapping on the annotation, add this inside your didSelect function:

let path = IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)
self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: path, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)

Then, in the collectionView cellForItemAt, I added the following:

self.mapView.selectAnnotation(self.mapView.annotations[indexPath.row], animated: false)

That will select the annotation that corresponds to the indexPath.row of your mapView annotations!

Hope that helped!